# JQuery selector for nested list items, only count click if its not on a link

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have several lists imbedded in lists.

- [X] Top List item 1
- - [X] Inner List item 1
- - [X] Inner List item 2
- - - [X] Inner Inner List item 1
- - - [X] Inner Inner List item 2
- - [X] Inner List item 3
- [X] Top List item 2
- [X] Top List item 3

The list is build progrmatically so this is just a very basic example, its actually much larger. The [X] is a checkbox. The numbers are links that when clicked toggle inner lists. So clicking the '1' on 'Top List item 1' Will make Inner List items 1, 2 and 3 display.

The list is structured like this:

```
<ul>
     <li> Top List item 1
          <ul>
               <li> Inner List item 1</li>
               <li> Inner List item 2
               <ul>
                    <li> Inner Inner List item 1</li>
                    <li> Inner Inner List item 2</li>
               </ul>
               </li>
               <li> Inner List item 3</li>
          </ul>
     </li>
     <li> Top List item 2</li>
     <li> Top List item 3</li>
</ul>
```

What I'm trying to do is that when someone clicks on a link in a list item it will toggle (show/hide) the inner list items.

However right now when I click on say 'Inner Inner list item 1' It checks  Top list item 1 and everything inside of it. Also when I click on a link to toggle the inner lists it checks all of the checkboxes.

Heres the Jquery.

```
$("li:has(a)").click(function() {
    var checkbox = $("input[type=checkbox]", this);
    checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop("checked"));

    if(checkbox.data('check')) {
        $("#" + checkbox.id + " input[type=checkbox").each(function(){
            this.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop("checked"));
        });
    }
});
```

Here's the Jquery I use to toggle it:

```
$("#patterns-data a[data-toggleid]").click(function() {
    var toggleid = $(this).data('toggleid');
    $("#" + toggleid).toggle();
});
```

So what I need is jquery that will allow the user to click anywhere on the list item to check its checkbox. If the list item has another list inside of it check all of those check boxes. And if the user clicks on a link to toggle the list ( tag) then don't check anything just toggle the list.

It may be a good idea to combine the two click events but Im not sure of the best way. Thank you for the help.

EDIT:

Ok I was doing research and found that the click event was being called multiple times, once for each li nesting. So I changed my code to use stopPropagation. It now only selects the clicked items checkbox. I still need it to select all list items checkboxes that are inside of the clicked list item.

$("li:has(a)", "#patterns-data").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();

```
    var checkbox = $("> input[type=checkbox]", this);
    checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop("checked"));

    $("> li", this).each(function(){
        var chkbox = $("> input[type=checkbox]", this);
        chkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.prop("checked"));
    });
});
```

Also it needs to ignore clicks on  tags so that the checkbox doesnt check when the user is trying to toggle the list.

Heres the code on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/683Te/

Comment: The is a ReferenceError in your code, `this.prop()` should be `$(this).prop()`

Comment: Heres JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/683Te/

Answer (score 3):

if i get your task right. Than you've better set one event listener, and work with it's target by your self. Some kind of delegetion.

```
$("#list").on("click", function(e){
   var target = e.target,
       targetName = target.tagName.toLowerCase();

   // and do everything by it tagname
   // the behavior is in example
});
```

and set change listener for checkbox, and just trigger it when you need.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/yj8bv/
All comments inside.

Comment: Nice green there :D I would have voted for it, too if 2 votes per post were possible